# I cannot manually add keyframes. I can only use auto keying. Why?

Tags: keyframes, timeline

Any time I press <kbd>I</kbd> whilst having a bone selected, then click *Only selected channels*, nothing happens. No yellow diamond appears on the timeline.

If I enable auto keying and move a bone, a keyframe is created with no problem, but I don't want to use auto keying.

Why is it not letting me create keyframes manually?

Comment: Hello, have you created a first keyframe for this bone? i (Only Selected Channels) will only work if there are already some keyframes

Comment: How would I create a first keyframe? Every guide online simply says to press I. they don't say anything other than that.

Comment: Press i in the 3d view in Pose mode with a bone selected

Comment: in other word, hover over the location or rotation for the object (or bone) and hit 'i'

Comment: This leads me back to my issue of Blender simply not creating a keyframe when I do this.